# Is there a way to bind overloaded class functions to a function object?

Tags: c++, function, overloading, bind

I am new to function binding concept.I need class member functions overloaded based on number of arguments and I want to bind these functions.I have one more doubt whether function object with variable arguments is possible.

Example:

```
class A{
    void print(int i)
    {
    };
    void print(int i,int j){
    };
}; 
//inside the object of A can I create function object like this??
auto f=std::bind(&A::print, this, std::placeholders::_1,...);
```

Comment: Could you give more details with an example code ?

Comment: What are you expecting `f` to do when you use it?

Comment: I want to call f(i) and f(i,j) based on some condition in later part of code

Answer (score 1):

In contexts with exact signature, the appropriate overload is selected automatically:

```
void (A::*p_i)(int) = &A::print;
void (A::*f_ii)(int, int) = &Demo::f;
```

In contexts where the signature cannot be deduced:

```
//auto f_a = &A::print; // ambiguous - which one???
```

you can explicitly select with a cast:

```
auto f_a = static_cast<void (A::*)(int)>(&A::print);
```

Comment: I want to use both member functions based on some condition, so static cast won't help

Comment: @SUNILKUMAR You cannot bind two different functions to the same object, even if they share the same name (i. e. are overloads). The type of the object returned by `std::bind(static_cast<void (A::*)(int)>(&A::print), ...)` possibly is different from the one returned by `std::bind(static_cast<void (A::*)(int, int)>(&A::print), ...);`, in any case they contain two *different* function pointers! So you'd need two such objects and select the appropriate one according to your condition.

Comment: @SUNILKUMAR Maybe a lambda fits better your needs: `auto f = [this](bool condition, int parameter) { (if condition) { print(parameter, SomeDefaultValue); } else { print(parameter); };`? Of course you could calculate the condition, possibly depending on further parameters, inside the lambda, too, if that appears appropriate to you...